# Solution for centralized download in offline environments

Tags: download-manager, proxy

I'm searching for a centralized download solution for an offline environment.

All of the computers have limited access to the internet via proxy and no download rights.

Does anyone know a scale-able all-in-one-solution for providing an terminal server like experience to interact with websites and download all types of files?

The downloaded files should be

- checked by two independent local malware scanner and
- copied to a location which can be accessed only by the user (and his computer) who downloaded the file and
- logged.

Currently we are using Windows 10 on our notebooks and Windows Server 2016+ or SLES 15 for virtual machines. The scanner should work on premise (no file upload to check in cloud) and there is no favorite scanner. There is currently no price limit defined which does not mean that the price does not matter :-)